# Remove last 4 digits from string if pattern matches

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching, substring

I'm trying to remove the last 4 digits from a string in Postgres if and only if they match a certain pattern: `[0][1-9][0][1-9]`.

Example:

```
1031610101 -> 103161
1234 -> 1234
123456 -> 123456
123405 -> 123405
```

I've tried a few approaches using substring, but somehow can't get this to work.
The length of the string is variable.

So far I've tried:

```
substring(value from '([\d](3,6}[0][1-9][0][1-9])') as "Result"
```

Comment: Are  you having trouble with matching via the regex or with extracting the string? Please provide a sample of the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier with [`regexp_replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(col, '0[1-9]0[1-9]$', '')
FROM   tbl;
```

`$` .. end of string

Answer (score -1):

SELECT SUBSTR('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP', 1, LENGTH('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP') - 4);

Syntax: SUBSTR('string',from_postion,length)

Comment: please add some description.

Comment: This could be simplified to `left(col, -4)`. More importantly, it does not answer the question.